# How Can I Map a New Type to an Element of a Tuple Type using a TypeScript Definition File?

Tags: typescript

I have a function signature imported from a third party library. I have a declaration file (`node-api.d.ts`) that I'd like to add a new type into which changes the type of one of the parameters to the function based off the imported function so that I catch any changes by the third-party lib author to their signature, like so:

```js
type ImportedMethod = (
  this: void,
  extension: object,
  otherParams: any
) => void

type ChangedMethod = (
  this: void,
  extension: MyExtensionType,
  otherParams: any
) => void
```

I think the way to do this is to use the `Parameters` utility function and get a *tuple type* (is that the correct term?) of the parameters, modify the type of the element I'm interested in, and then spread that new *tuple type* in a new function signature:

```js
// [extension: object, otherParams: any]
type Params = Parameters<ImportedMethod>

// @TODO: Figure out how to transform the `extension`
// element's type of my "tuple type" to a new type

type ChangedMethod = (
  ...args: ModifiedParams
) => void
```

I can't figure out how to change the type of an element of the *tuple type*. I think I need to use mapped and conditional types, but I'm not sure how to introduce the string literal as a condition:

```js
type SwapExtensionElement<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends 'extension' ? MyExtensionType : T[K]
}

type ModifiedParams = SwapExtensionElement<ImportedMethod>
// [extension: object, otherParams: any]
```

I'd sure appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the position, [you can `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) parts of the parameters tuple, and the reassemble new parameters.

In this case you need everything but the first paramter, since that one is getting replaced. So let's use a utility type called `Tail`:

```
type Tail<T extends unknown[]> =
    T extends [infer _, ...infer Rest] ? Rest : never

type Test = Tail<[1, 2, 3]> // [2, 3]
```

This takes a tuple and pulls out the first element to an ignored type `_`, and everything after into `Rest` and then resolves to `Rest`.

You can then create your method type like this:

```
type ChangedMethod = (
  this: void,
  extension: MyExtensionType,
  ...args: Tail<Params>
) => void
```

The IDE then reports the type of `ChangedMethod` as:

```
type ChangedMethod = (this: void, extension: MyExtensionType, otherParams: any) => void
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgtmA9gJ2BAJgWQsAFo9KAXigAoAoKKPASwGcAuKAN0RvQBpKoIAPNAHZ0aiAU0QAjAFYQAxsC5VEeCMgAKAQ2Qa4jKBoEhyASmIA+Fm3TkboSFAAqGmgBsAPA578IA9HSgArgIA1gKIAO4CANoAuhZE3FSefIJ+UFE0AgBmqlAA+hxQAHQlmTnIUABKEHTAMVAA-FU1wFBMAhDMqrbg0JggAKLeQiICDr3EUADe+u0BcBK5AL499praupPrOjiqdG7wSKgY2HgEZjbkdtAAwrgGAOYnOPiEJBRUtHqs7IpegsJREx+kMAaNxpA-iUiloHnonK43NtdBdTEQLD9rOQgA)

Comment: Thank you Alex, I did come across examples using infer to get at the first or last parameter in a tuple type. Right now the parameter I'm interested in is ordered first by the third-party library author so your solution will work for me. I'm hoping to find a more general way to do this because I don't control the incoming type, and that parameter could get moved in the signature (and if it comes up again in a different context where the parameter is in the middle I won't know how to do it).

Comment: If the parameter moves, I don't know how you could know which one to replace then. You could maybe match on the type instead, but that type may appear at multiple places in the argument list. And you can't match on the argument name at all, because it's really just for intellisense and you can't look it up in any query on the type. So I think position is your best bet here.

Comment: Not being able to match on the argument name is the information that helps me greatly. I remember reading that somewhere in the release notes, but I didn't grasp what it meant in the context I saw it.